# Peak-finding algorithm for Python/SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, fft, hough-transform

I can write something myself by finding zero-crossings of the first derivative or something, but it seems like a common-enough function to be included in standard libraries.  Anyone know of one?

My particular application is a 2D array, but usually it would be used for finding peaks in FFTs, etc.

Specifically, in these kinds of problems, there are multiple strong peaks, and then lots of smaller "peaks" that are just caused by noise that should be ignored.  These are just examples; not my actual data:

1-dimensional peaks:

[image: FFT output with peaks]

2-dimensional peaks:

[image: Radon transform output with circled peak]

The peak-finding algorithm would find the location of these peaks (not just their values), and ideally would find the true inter-sample peak, not just the index with maximum value, probably using [quadratic interpolation](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Quadratic_Peak_Interpolation.html) or something.

Typically you only care about a few strong peaks, so they'd either be chosen because they're above a certain threshold, or because they're the first *n* peaks of an ordered list, ranked by amplitude.

As I said, I know how to write something like this myself.  I'm just asking if there's a pre-existing function or package that's known to work well.

**Update:**

I [translated a MATLAB script](http://gist.github.com/250860) and it works decently for the 1-D case, but could be better.

**Updated update:**

sixtenbe [created a better version](https://gist.github.com/1178136) for the 1-D case.

Comment: @endolith Do you have the original MATLAB file that you translated to python for this? Thanks!

Comment: @Mohammad: http://billauer.co.il/peakdet.html https://gist.github.com/250860#file_peakdet.m

Comment: What about this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640362/913098) answer is worth noting here.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The function [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), as its name suggests, is useful for this. But it's important to understand well its parameters `width`, `threshold`, `distance` **and above all `prominence`** to get a good peak extraction.

According to my tests and the documentation, the concept of **prominence** is "the useful concept" to keep the good peaks, and discard the noisy peaks.

What is [(topographic) prominence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence)? It is *"the minimum height necessary to descend to get from the summit to any higher terrain"*, as it can be seen here:

[image]

The idea is:

> The higher the prominence, the more "important" the peak is.

Test:

[image]

I used a (noisy) frequency-varying sinusoid on purpose because it shows many difficulties. We can see that the `width` parameter is not very useful here because if you set a minimum `width` too high, then it won't be able to track very close peaks in the high frequency part. If you set `width` too low, you would have many unwanted peaks in the left part of the signal. Same problem with `distance`. `threshold` only compares with the direct neighbours, which is not useful here. `prominence` is the one that gives the best solution. Note that you can combine many of these parameters!

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = np.sin(2*np.pi*(2**np.linspace(2,10,1000))*np.arange(1000)/48000) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) * 0.15
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=20)
peaks2, _ = find_peaks(x, prominence=1)      # BEST!
peaks3, _ = find_peaks(x, width=20)
peaks4, _ = find_peaks(x, threshold=0.4)     # Required vertical distance to its direct neighbouring samples, pretty useless
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "xr"); plt.plot(x); plt.legend(['distance'])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(peaks2, x[peaks2], "ob"); plt.plot(x); plt.legend(['prominence'])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(peaks3, x[peaks3], "vg"); plt.plot(x); plt.legend(['width'])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(peaks4, x[peaks4], "xk"); plt.plot(x); plt.legend(['threshold'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This's what I am after. But do you happen to know any implementation that finds prominence in 2D array?

Comment: @Jason I just came across [Peak detection in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array) and it's worth reading!

Comment: `wlen` is also extremely useful when using `prominence` if you have some values that are prominent and also close to the peak you are trying to find. Worked extremely well for my signal.

Comment: In the answer, you chose the value of `prominence` to be `1`. How does one find out the best value for `prominence`. Would we have to do it by trial and error?

Comment: @thentangler the prominence is relative to the height to descend, so by looking at the amplitude of the signal (here it goes from -1 to 1), you have the right order of magnitude with something like `1`.

Comment: "prominence look not only at the single sample with the local maximum but also at the signal shape around the peak" - [ref](https://www.samproell.io/posts/signal/peak-finding-python-js/)

Answer (score 52):

I'm looking at a similar problem, and I've found some of the best references come from chemistry (from peaks finding in mass-spec data).  For a good thorough review of peaking finding algorithms read [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2631518/).  This is one of the best clearest reviews of peak finding techniques that I've run across.  (Wavelets are the best for finding peaks of this sort in noisy data.).

It looks like your peaks are clearly defined and aren't hidden in the noise.  That being the case I'd recommend using smooth savtizky-golay derivatives to find the peaks (If you just differentiate the data above you'll have a mess of false positives.).  This is a very effective technique and is pretty easy to implemented (you do need a matrix class w/ basic operations).  If you simply find the zero crossing of the first S-G derivative I think you'll be happy.

Comment: I was looking for a general purpose solution, not one that only works on those particular images.  I adapted a MATLAB script to Python and it works decently.

Comment: why are zeros of derivative better than just testing if a middle out of three points is larger or smaller of the other two. i have already applied sg transfor, seems like an extra cost.

Answer (score 22):

There is a function in scipy named `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt` which sounds like is suitable for your needs, however I don't have experience with it so I cannot recommend..

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html

Answer (score 21):

For those not sure about which peak-finding algorithms to use in Python, here a rapid overview of the alternatives: https://github.com/MonsieurV/py-findpeaks

Wanting myself an equivalent to the MatLab `findpeaks` function, I've found that the [detect_peaks function](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/demotu/BMC/blob/master/notebooks/DetectPeaks.ipynb) from Marcos Duarte is a good catch.

Pretty easy to use:

```
import numpy as np
from vector import vector, plot_peaks
from libs import detect_peaks
print('Detect peaks with minimum height and distance filters.')
indexes = detect_peaks.detect_peaks(vector, mph=7, mpd=2)
print('Peaks are: %s' % (indexes))
```

Which will give you:

[image: detect_peaks results]

Comment: Since this post was written, the `find_peaks` function was added to `scipy`.

Answer (score 8):

To detect both positive and negative peaks, [PeakDetect](https://github.com/anaxilaus/peakdetect) is helpful.

```
from peakdetect import peakdetect

peaks = peakdetect(data, lookahead=20) 
# Lookahead is the distance to look ahead from a peak to determine if it is the actual peak. 
# Change lookahead as necessary 
higherPeaks = np.array(peaks[0])
lowerPeaks = np.array(peaks[1])
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(higherPeaks[:,0], higherPeaks[:,1], 'ro')
plt.plot(lowerPeaks[:,0], lowerPeaks[:,1], 'ko')
```

[image: PeakDetection]

Answer (score 6):

Detecting peaks in a spectrum in a reliable way has been studied quite a bit, for example all the work on sinusoidal modelling for music/audio signals in the 80ies. Look for "Sinusoidal Modeling" in the literature.

If your signals are as clean as the example, a simple "give me something with an amplitude higher than N neighbours" should work reasonably well. If you have noisy signals, a simple but effective way is to look at your peaks in time, to track them: you then detect spectral lines instead of spectral peaks. IOW, you compute the FFT on a sliding window of your signal, to get a set of spectrum in time (also called spectrogram). You then look at the evolution of the spectral peak in time (i.e. in consecutive windows).

Comment: Oh, you're talking about using STFT instead of FFT.  This question isn't about FFTs specifically; that's just an example.  It's about finding the peaks in any general 1D or 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

There are standard statistical functions and methods for finding outliers to data, which is probably what you need in the first case. Using derivatives would solve your second. I'm not sure for a method which solves both continuous functions and sampled data, however.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that what you are looking for is provided by SciPy.  I would write the code myself, in this situation.

The spline interpolation and smoothing from scipy.interpolate are quite nice and might be quite helpful in fitting peaks and then finding the location of their maximum.

Comment: My apologies, but I think that this should be a comment, not an answer. It just suggests writing it by oneself, with a vague suggestion for functions which might be useful (the ones in Paul's answer are much more relevant, incidentally).

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the definition of "peak" is vague if without further specifications.  For example, for the following series, would you call 5-4-5 one peak or two?

1-2-1-2-1-1-5-4-5-1-1-5-1

In this case, you'll need at least two thresholds: 1) a high threshold only above which can an extreme value register as a peak; and 2) a low threshold so that extreme values separated by small values below it will become two peaks.

Peak detection is a well-studied topic in Extreme Value Theory literature, also known as "declustering of extreme values".  Its typical applications include identifying hazard events based on continuous readings of environmental variables e.g. analysing wind speed to detect storm events.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned at the bottom of this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656367/find-peaks-location-in-a-spectrum-numpy/61841804#61841804) there is no universal definition of a peak. Therefore a universal *algorithm* that finds peaks cannot work without bringing in additional assumptions (conditions, parameters etc.). This page provides some of the most *stripped down* suggestions. All the literature listed in the answers above is a more or less roundabout manner to do the same so feel free to take your pick.

In any case, it is your duty to narrow down the properties a feature needs to have in order to be classified as a peak, based on your experience and properties of spectra (curves) in question (noise, sampling, bandwidths, etc.)