# How to find peaks in a spectrogram Python

Tags: python, max, spectrogram, audio-fingerprinting

### Introduction

I am trying to find peaks in amplitude within a spectrogram I have produced that plots frequency against time and amplitude as the third axis.

I have looked through and attempted to code a solution using `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt` however the official reference guide did not explain what was meant by the `widths` parameter.

### Question:

When finding peaks using `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt` will it return the frequency-time coordinates? If not is there another library or method to use to return the coordinates of local maxima?

What is the `widths` parameter within `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt`?

As the `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt` deals with arrays why do you still need to plot a spectrogram in order to find local maxima?

### Here is the code i have been using to create the spectrogram:

```
    import numpy as np      
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    import scipy.io.wavfile     
    from scipy import signal

    def create_spectrogram(audio):
        rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(audio)        
        data_1D = data.flatten()
        plt.specgram(data_1D, NFFT = 64, Fs = 64, noverlap=32)  
        plt.savefig("melody")  
        plt.show()      


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        audio = "melody.WAV"        
        create_spectrogram(audio)
```

### Here is the outputted Spectrogram:

[image: Here is the outputted Spectrogram:]

Links:
`scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt` reference guide: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far?

Comment: `find_peaks_cwt` is for 1-D array. If you want to find local peaks in your 2-D spectrogram, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a bit more information as to how exactly is your data stored in your code? Is it a numpy array, a scipy.signal.spectrogram or simple python lists? A snippet of code would help a lot in trying to help you find a good solution.

For the moment the only "easy" way I would suggest is to have a look at [numpy.amax()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html), choosing wisely the value given to the axis parameter, should get you the maximum you are looking for.