# Peak finding in a 3D noise-free scalar field using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have found multiple questions about peak finding in the forum. However, questions and solutions are almost exclusively only treating the 1D case and usually assume noisy data.

I have a 3D field with essentially no noise. I would like to find (i) all the peaks in the field above a certain threshold (the field is smooth, so their number should be limited) and (ii) all the peaks in the field that have a certain property: say, the area around the peak has a minimal extent, say of 5 ml.

Example of the field (it's one cut through a brain, the actual field is 3D):[image]

Rather than cooking something up myself, I was hoping that the question is generic enough that there already exits a working implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array) method should work in 3d I think, but not sure how to set the binary erosion filter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `findpeaks` which you may find useful ([link](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks/pages/html/Installation.html)).

[image]