# How to find peaks in python for a 3D plot?

Tags: python

I have plotted a 3D radiation plot using Python, with theta on the x-axis and phi on the y-axis and magnitudes along z.  I initially used numpy.meshgrid to create the 2d array for thetas and phis. Now how can I find the peak points( main lobe and side lobes) from this graph?
find_peak function of the scipy.signal library seems to deal with 1d array only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Peak detection in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `maximum_filter` from `scipy.ndimage.filters`, or even just a simple thresholding could do the trick, provided prior smoothing/transformations like erosion/dilation.