# Numpy equivalent of Matlab's findpeaks function?

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Peak-finding algorithm for Python/SciPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713335/peak-finding-algorithm-for-python-scipy)

I'm looking to find local maxima in a vector of floating-point numbers, as is done by Matlab's findpeaks function.

Does numpy have a similar function?

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1713335/125507, which resulted in the code linked to by the answer that you accepted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html

or:

https://gist.github.com/1178136

Comment: looks promising.  It seems my google-fu skills have been dropping lately, thanks!

Comment: The module on github seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.  Many thanks!