# Solving multiple linear sparse matrix equations: "numpy.linalg.solve" vs. "scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have to solve a large amount of linear matrix equations of the type "Ax=B" for x where A is a sparse matrix with mainly the main diagonal populated and B is a vector.

My first approach was to use dense numpy arrays for this purpose with numpy.linalg.solve, and it works fine with a (N,n,n)-dimensional array with N being the number of linear matrix equations and n the square matrix dimension. I first used it with a for loop iterating through all equations, which in fact is rather slow. But then realized that you can also pass the (N,n,n)-dimensional matrix directly to numpy.linalg.solve without any for loop (which by the way I did not find in the documentation I read). This already gave a good increase in computation speed (details see below).

However, because I have sparse matrices, I also had a look at the scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve function which does similar things like the corresponding numpy function. Using a for loop iterating through all equations is much, much faster than the numpy solution, but it seems impossible to pass the (N,n,n)-dimesional array directly to scipy´s spsolve.

Here is what I tried so far:

First, I calculate some fictional A matrices and B vectors with random numbers for test purposes, both sparse and dense:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve

number_of_systems = 100 #corresponds to N in the text
number_of_data_points = 1000 #corresponds to n in the text

#calculation of sample matrices (dense and sparse)
A_sparse = np.empty(number_of_systems,dtype=object)
A_dense = np.empty((number_of_systems,number_of_data_points,number_of_data_points))

for ii in np.arange(number_of_systems):
    A_sparse[ii] = sparse.spdiags(np.random.random(number_of_data_points),0,number_of_data_points,number_of_data_points)
    A_dense[ii] = A_sparse[ii].todense()

#calculation of sample vectors
B = np.random.random((number_of_systems,number_of_data_points))
```

1) First approach: numpy.linalg.solve with for loop:

```py
def solve_dense_3D(A,B):
    results = np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[1]))
    for ii in np.arange(A.shape[0]):
        results[ii] = np.linalg.solve(A[ii],B[ii])
    return results

result_dense_for = solve_dense_3D(A_dense,B)
```

Timing:

```py
timeit(solve_dense_3D(A_dense,B))
1.25 s ± 27.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

2) Second approach: Passing the (N,n,n)-dimensional matrix directly to numpy.linalg.solve:

```py
result_dense = np.linalg.solve(A_dense,B)
```

Timing:

```py
timeit(np.linalg.solve(A_dense,B))
769 ms ± 9.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

3) Third approach: Using scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve with a for loop:

```py
def solve_sparse_3D(A,B):
    results = np.empty((A.shape[0],A[0].shape[0]))
    for ii in np.arange(A.shape[0]):
        results[ii] = spsolve(A[ii],B[ii])
    return results

result_sparse_for = solve_sparse_3D(A_sparse,B)
```

Timing:

```py
timeit(solve_sparse_3D(A_sparse,B))
30.9 ms ± 132 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It is obvoius that there is an advantage being able to omit the for loop from approach 1 and 2. By far the fastest alternative is, as could probably be expected, approach 3 with sparse matrices.

Because the number of equations in this example is still rather low for me and because I have to do things like that very often, I would be happy if there was a solution using scipy´s sparse matrices without a for loop. Is anybody aware of a way to achieve that? Or maybe there is another way to solve the problem in an even different way? I would be happy for suggestions.

Comment: I'm not so sure if losing the loop will help (it's slow python-looping vs. indication of independence; where the latter might be more important in sparse operations). Without thinking too much of it, it feels, like you could just build a [block-diag matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) of your independent problems (and growing b in sync of course).

Comment: sascha, I am not sure either. I hope that a similar effect can somehow be achieved like with the numpy approaches, which saves roughly 40% computation time when not using the for loop. Apart from that, I will have a look at your suggestion.

Comment: The loop itself shouldn't be a problem here, though numpy/scipy function overhead may be. Also, running your code I get a sparse efficiency warning. Turns out as it stands the sparse code spends more than half its time converting to csc/csr format.

Comment: Is this a valid test? The matrices are all diagonal, so that inversion is just element-wise division of the right side vector by the diagonal. `spsolve` recognizes this structure and does just that much operations.

Comment: LutzL, I get your point. In fact, my real data does not look quite as clean. Therefore, I repeated the methods with some real data (which are a little hard to show here) with qualitatively similar results. So I would assume that the test is more or less "valid".

Comment: Paul Panzer, you have a point here: Adding format='csr' to all sparse matrix constructions brings approach 3 down to 17.4 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small demo outlining the idea from my comment above:

```
""" YOUR CODE (only imports changed + deterministic randomness) """

import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
from scipy.sparse import block_diag
from time import perf_counter as pc

np.random.seed(0)

number_of_systems = 100 #corresponds to N in the text
number_of_data_points = 1000 #corresponds to n in the text

#calculation of sample matrices (dense and sparse)
A_sparse = np.empty(number_of_systems,dtype=object)
A_dense = np.empty((number_of_systems,number_of_data_points,number_of_data_points))

for ii in np.arange(number_of_systems):
    A_sparse[ii] = sparse.spdiags(np.random.random(number_of_data_points),0,number_of_data_points,number_of_data_points)
    A_dense[ii] = A_sparse[ii].todense()

#calculation of sample vectors
B = np.random.random((number_of_systems,number_of_data_points))

def solve_sparse_3D(A,B):
    results = np.empty((A.shape[0],A[0].shape[0]))
    for ii in np.arange(A.shape[0]):
        results[ii] = spsolve(A[ii],B[ii])
    return results

start = pc()
result_sparse_for = solve_sparse_3D(A_sparse,B)
end = pc()
print(result_sparse_for)
print(end - start)

""" ALTERNATIVE APPROACH """

def solve_sparse_3D_blockdiag(A,B):
    oldN = B.shape[0]

    A_ = block_diag(A)    # huge sparse block-matrix of independent problems
    B_ = B.ravel()        # flattened vector

    results = spsolve(A_, B_)
    return results.reshape(oldN, -1)    # unflatten results

start = pc()
result_sparse_for = solve_sparse_3D_blockdiag(A_sparse,B)
end = pc()
print(result_sparse_for)
print(end - start)
```

which outputs

```
[[ 0.97529866  1.26406276  0.83348888 ...  0.99310639  3.90781207
0.16724226]
[ 1.23398934 28.82088739  1.6955886  ...  1.85011686  0.23386882
1.17208753]
[ 0.92864777  0.22248781  0.09445412 ...  2.5080376   0.91701228
0.97266564]
...
[ 0.33087093  0.89034736  1.7523883  ...  0.2171746   4.89236164
0.31546549]
[ 1.2163625   3.0100941   0.87216264 ...  1.62105596  0.33211353
2.07929302]
[ 5.35677404  1.23830776  0.16073721 ...  0.26492506  0.53676822
3.73192617]]
0.08764066299999995

###

[[ 0.97529866  1.26406276  0.83348888 ...  0.99310639  3.90781207
0.16724226]
[ 1.23398934 28.82088739  1.6955886  ...  1.85011686  0.23386882
1.17208753]
[ 0.92864777  0.22248781  0.09445412 ...  2.5080376   0.91701228
0.97266564]
...
[ 0.33087093  0.89034736  1.7523883  ...  0.2171746   4.89236164
0.31546549]
[ 1.2163625   3.0100941   0.87216264 ...  1.62105596  0.33211353
2.07929302]
[ 5.35677404  1.23830776  0.16073721 ...  0.26492506  0.53676822
3.73192617]]
0.07241856000000013
```

There are some things to do:

- use your original more sane benchmarking-approach
- build the block_diag in the correct sparse format to get rid of some potential warning and slowdown: see docs
- tune spsolve's parameter `permc_spec`

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting. If I understand correctly what you did you combined all sparse matrices into one really big sparse matrix while still keeping them independent from each other. I tested the code and it finished in 54.2 ms with the correct result, so it is a little slower than using the for loop.

Comment: Yes benchmarking is important. I also don't see another approach besides non-python looping (cython an co.). I also expect one perm_spec to dominate the others (as this operation in general ignores independence; but a diag-block structure is common, although i don't have the name/buzzword right now). But maybe it's already the default.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I tested different options for permc_spec without much of an effect. But I did also test your approach for another problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350711/baseline-correction-for-spectroscopic-data) and there I was able to reduce computation time from 88 s to 42 s without the for loop. So if it makes sense seems to depend very much on the data you have.

Comment: I must have done something wrong with the permc_spec testing in my first trials. 'NATURAL' instead of 'COLAMD' brings the time down further from 42 s to 32.8 s with the example from the other question mentioned in my previous comment. For the example from this question, together with building the sparse matrices as 'csr' from the beginning, it reduces the time to 40.3 ms without the for loop and to 13.6 ms with the for loop.