# How to subtract baseline from spectrum with rising tail in python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, spectrum, baseline

I have a spectrum that I want to subtract a baseline from. The spectrum data are:

```
1.484043000000000001e+00    1.121043091000000004e+03
1.472555999999999976e+00    1.140899658000000045e+03
1.461239999999999872e+00    1.135047851999999921e+03
1.450093000000000076e+00    1.153286499000000049e+03
1.439112000000000169e+00    1.158624877999999853e+03
1.428292000000000117e+00    1.249718872000000147e+03
1.417629999999999946e+00    1.491854857999999922e+03
1.407121999999999984e+00    2.524922362999999677e+03
1.396767000000000092e+00    4.102439940999999635e+03
1.386559000000000097e+00    4.013319579999999860e+03
1.376497999999999999e+00    3.128252441000000090e+03
1.366578000000000070e+00    2.633181152000000111e+03
1.356797999999999949e+00    2.340077147999999852e+03
1.347154999999999880e+00    2.099404540999999881e+03
1.337645999999999891e+00    2.012083983999999873e+03
1.328268000000000004e+00    2.052154540999999881e+03
1.319018999999999942e+00    2.061067871000000196e+03
1.309895999999999949e+00    2.205770507999999609e+03
1.300896999999999970e+00    2.199266602000000148e+03
1.292019000000000029e+00    2.317792235999999775e+03
1.283260000000000067e+00    2.357031494000000293e+03
1.274618000000000029e+00    2.434981689000000188e+03
1.266089999999999938e+00    2.540746337999999923e+03
1.257675000000000098e+00    2.605709472999999889e+03
1.249370000000000092e+00    2.667244141000000127e+03
1.241172999999999860e+00    2.800522704999999860e+03
```

I've taken only every 20th data point from the actual data file, but the general shape is preserved.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
share = the_above_array
plt.plot(share)
```

Original_spectrum

[image]

There is a clear tail in around the high x values. Assume the tail is an artifact and needs to be removed. I've tried solutions using the [ALS algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156532/python-baseline-correction-library) by P. Eilers, a [rubberband approach](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/how-to-perform-a-rubberband-correction-on-spectroscopic-data), and the [peakutils](https://plotly.com/python/v3/baseline-subtraction/) package, but these end up subtracting the tail and creating a rise around the low x values or not creating a suitable baseline.

ALS algorithim, in this example I am using `lam=1E6` and `p=0.001`; these were the best parameters I was able to manually find:

```
# ALS approach
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
def baseline_als(y, lam, p, niter=10):
    L = len(y)
    D = sparse.csc_matrix(np.diff(np.eye(L), 2))
    w = np.ones(L)
    for i in range(niter):
      W = sparse.spdiags(w, 0, L, L)
      Z = W + lam * D.dot(D.transpose())
      z = spsolve(Z, w*y)
      w = p * (y > z) + (1-p) * (y < z)
    return z

baseline = baseline_als(share[:,1], 1E6, 0.001)
baseline_subtracted = share[:,1] - baseline
plt.plot(baseline_subtracted)
```

ALS_plot
[image]

Rubberband approach:

```
# rubberband approach
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
def rubberband(x, y):
    # Find the convex hull
    v = ConvexHull(share).vertices
    # Rotate convex hull vertices until they start from the lowest one
    v = np.roll(v, v.argmax())
    # Leave only the ascending part
    v = v[:v.argmax()]
    # Create baseline using linear interpolation between vertices
    return np.interp(x, x[v], y[v])

baseline_rubber = rubberband(share[:,0], share[:,1])
intensity_rubber = share[:,1] - baseline_rubber
plt.plot(intensity_rubber)
```

Rubber_plot
[image]

peakutils package:

```
# peakutils approach
import peakutils
baseline_peakutils = peakutils.baseline(share[:,1])
intensity_peakutils = share[:,1] - baseline_peakutils
plt.plot(intensity_peakutils)
```

Peakutils_plot
[image]

Are there any suggestions, aside from masking the low x value data, for constructing a baseline and subtracting the tail without creating a rise in the low x values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a set of similar ALS algorithms [here](https://irfpy.irf.se/projects/ica/_modules/irfpy/ica/baseline.html). One of these algorithms, asymmetrically reweighted penalized least squares smoothing (`arpls`), gives a slightly better fit than `als`.

```
# arpls approach
from scipy.linalg import cholesky
def arpls(y, lam=1e4, ratio=0.05, itermax=100):
    r"""
    Baseline correction using asymmetrically
    reweighted penalized least squares smoothing
    Sung-June Baek, Aaron Park, Young-Jin Ahna and Jaebum Choo,
    Analyst, 2015, 140, 250 (2015)
    """
    N = len(y)
    D = sparse.eye(N, format='csc')
    D = D[1:] - D[:-1]  # numpy.diff( ,2) does not work with sparse matrix. This is a workaround.
    D = D[1:] - D[:-1]
    H = lam * D.T * D
    w = np.ones(N)
    for i in range(itermax):
        W = sparse.diags(w, 0, shape=(N, N))
        WH = sparse.csc_matrix(W + H)
        C = sparse.csc_matrix(cholesky(WH.todense()))
        z = spsolve(C, spsolve(C.T, w * y))
        d = y - z
        dn = d[d < 0]
        m = np.mean(dn)
        s = np.std(dn)
        wt = 1. / (1 + np.exp(2 * (d - (2 * s - m)) / s))
        if np.linalg.norm(w - wt) / np.linalg.norm(w) < ratio:
            break
        w = wt
    return z

baseline = baseline_als(share[:,1], 1E6, 0.001)
baseline_subtracted = share[:,1] - baseline
plt.plot(baseline_subtracted, 'r', label='als')

baseline_arpls = arpls(share[:,1], 1e5, 0.1)
intensity_arpls = share[:,1] - baseline_arpls
plt.plot(intensity_arpls, label='arpls')

plt.legend()
```

ARPLS plot

[image]

Fortunately, this improvement becomes better when using the data from the entire spectrum:

[image]

Note the parameters for either algorithm were different. For now, I think the `arpls` algorithm is as close as I can get, at least for spectra that look like this. We'll see how robust the algorithm can fit spectra with different shapes. Of course, I am always open to suggestions or improvements!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [RamPy](https://github.com/charlesll/rampy) library in python, which proposes various baseline subtraction algorithms. This includes splines, ARPLS, ALS, polynomial functions, and many more. It also offers various other features, such as resampling, normalisation, and peak fitting examples.

In your case, a simple spline function fitted before and after the peak should easily do the job. Have a look at [this example Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/charlesll/rampy/blob/master/examples/baseline_fit.ipynb).