# Counting Peaks in a Time Series

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I am counting the number of peaks and troughs in a numpy array.

I have a numpy array like so:

```
stack = np.array([0,0,5,4,1,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1])
```

Plotted, this data looks like something like this:

[image: Time Series plot of 'stack'array]

I am looking to find the number of peaks in this time series:

This is my code, which works well for an example like this where there are clear peaks and troughs in the time series representation. My code returns the indexes of the array where peaks have been found.

```
#example
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

stack = 
np.array([0,0,5,4,1,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1])

# for local maxima
y = argrelextrema(stack, np.greater)

print(y)
```

Result:

```
(array([ 2,  7, 10, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26]),)
```

There are 8 clear peaks that have been found and can be correctly counted.

My solution does not appear to work well with data that is less clear cut and more messy.

An array below does not work well and does not find the peaks that I need:

```
array([ 0.        ,  5.70371806,  5.21210157,  3.71144767,  3.9020162 ,
    3.87735984,  3.89030171,  6.00879918,  4.91964227,  4.37756275,
    4.03048542,  4.26943028,  4.02080471,  7.54749062,  3.9150576 ,
    4.08933851,  4.01794766,  4.13217794,  4.15081972,  8.11213474,
    4.6561735 ,  4.54128693,  3.63831552,  4.3415324 ,  4.15944019,
    8.55171441,  4.86579459,  4.13221943,  4.487663  ,  3.95297979,
    4.35334706,  9.91524674,  4.44738182,  4.32562141,  4.420753  ,
    3.54525697,  4.07070637,  9.21055852,  4.87767969,  4.04429321,
    4.50863677,  3.38154581,  3.73663523,  3.83690315,  6.95321174,
    5.11325128,  4.50351938,  4.38070175,  3.20891173,  3.51142661,
    7.80429569,  3.98677631,  3.89820773,  4.15614576,  3.47369797,
    3.73355768,  8.85240649,  6.0876192 ,  3.57292324,  4.43599135,
    3.77887259,  3.62302175,  7.03985076,  4.91916556,  4.22246518,
    3.48080777,  3.26199699,  2.89680969,  3.19251448])
```

Plotted, this data looks like:

[image: Data 2]

And the same code returns:

```
(array([ 1,  4,  7, 11, 13, 15, 19, 23, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 44, 50, 53,
   56, 59, 62]),)
```

This output incorrectly counts data points as peaks.

**Ideal Output**

The ideal output should return the number of clear peaks, 11 in this case which are located at indexes:

```
[1,7,13,19,25,31,37,44,50,56,62]
```

I believe my problem comes about because of the aggregated nature of the argrelextrema function.

Comment: This kind of depends on how you define a "clearly defined peak." To the eye, it seems simple, but what sort of rule are you looking to use in your program?

Comment: This may be a possible duplicate of [Peak-finding algorithm for Python/SciPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713335/peak-finding-algorithm-for-python-scipy). Note that this solution does offer the `prominence` input which will allow you to specify how prominent a peak should be to count.

Comment: Looks like you need to define some threshold and search the values that are greater than it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some treshold to find peaks:

```
prev = stack[0] or 0.001
threshold = 0.5
peaks = []

for num, i in enumerate(stack[1:], 1):
    if (i - prev) / prev > threshold:
        peaks.append(num)
    prev = i or 0.001

print(peaks)
# [1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37, 44, 50, 56, 62]
```

Comment: This answer seems to work well. Thanks! What does the 0.001 represent? And how did you pick a threshold value of 0.5?

Comment: @Murray You are welcome. `i or 0.001` solves the problem of dividing by zero. This expression is evaluated to 0.001 if `i` is 0 (you can also use 0.1, depends on your data). I just took the first value of 0.5 and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

You should try **find_peaks** in the scipy.signal module

### Example with your data

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([ 0.        ,  5.70371806,  5.21210157,  3.71144767, 3.9020162 ,  3.87735984,  3.89030171,  6.00879918,  4.91964227,  4.37756275,
4.03048542,  4.26943028,  4.02080471,  7.54749062,  3.9150576 ,
4.08933851,  4.01794766,  4.13217794,  4.15081972,  8.11213474,
4.6561735 ,  4.54128693,  3.63831552,  4.3415324 ,  4.15944019,
8.55171441,  4.86579459,  4.13221943,  4.487663  ,  3.95297979,
4.35334706,  9.91524674,  4.44738182,  4.32562141,  4.420753  ,
3.54525697,  4.07070637,  9.21055852,  4.87767969,  4.04429321,
4.50863677,  3.38154581,  3.73663523,  3.83690315,  6.95321174,
5.11325128,  4.50351938,  4.38070175,  3.20891173,  3.51142661,
7.80429569,  3.98677631,  3.89820773,  4.15614576,  3.47369797,
3.73355768,  8.85240649,  6.0876192 ,  3.57292324,  4.43599135,
3.77887259,  3.62302175,  7.03985076,  4.91916556,  4.22246518,
3.48080777,  3.26199699,  2.89680969,  3.19251448])

# Here you should fine tune parameters to get what you want
peaks = find_peaks(a, prominence=1.5)
print("Peaks position:", peaks[0])

# Plotting
plt.plot(a)
plt.title("Finding Peaks")

[plt.axvline(p, c='C3', linewidth=0.3) for p in peaks[0]]

plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image: plot]

#### Output

```
# Peaks position: [ 1  7 13 19 25 31 37 44 50 56 62]
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `argrelextrema` gets you most of the way. It has all the peaks that you want, but it also has some extra ones. You need to come up with a criteria that suits your case and filter out the peaks you don't want.

For example, if you don't want peaks that are less than 5, you could do this:

```
In [17]: result = argrelextrema(a, np.greater)                                                           

In [18]: result                                                                                          
Out[18]: 
(array([ 1,  4,  7, 11, 13, 15, 19, 23, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 44, 50, 53,
        56, 59, 62]),)

In [19]: result[0][a[result[0]] > 5]                                                                     
Out[19]: array([ 1,  7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37, 44, 50, 56, 62])
```