# How to programatically report reasonable local maximas and minimas in a data set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, octave, analytics

I have an array of y-values which are evenly spaced along the x-axis and I need to programmatically find the "troughs". I think either Octave or Python3 are good language choices for this problem as I know both have strong math capabilities.

I thought to interpolate the function and look for where the derivatives are 0, but that would require my human eyes to first analyze the resulting graph to know where the maxima and minima already were, but I need this entire thing to be automatic; as to work with an arbitrary dataset.

It dawned on me that this problem likely had an existing solution in a Python3 or Octave function or library, but I could not find one. Does there exist a library to automatically report local maximas and minimas within a dataset?

#### More Info

My current planned approach is to implement a sort of "n-day moving average" with a threshold. After initializing the first day moving average, I'll watch for the next moving average to move above or below it by a threshold. If it moves higher then I'll consider myself in a "rising" period. If it moves lower then I'm in a "falling" period. While I'm in a rising period, I'll update the maximum observed moving average until the current moving average is sufficiently below the previous maximum.

At this point, I'll consider myself in a "falling" period. I'll lock in the point where the moving average was previously highest, and then repeat except using inverse logic for the "falling" period.

It seemed to me that this is probably a pretty common problem though, so I'm sure there's an existing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python answer:

This is a common problem, with existing solutions.
Examples include:

- [peakutils](https://peakutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [scipy find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)
- see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612432/4117624) question

in all cases, you'll have to test your parameters to have what you want.

Comment: The scipy find peaks worked perfectly. I was even able to find the valleys by multiplying my values by -1 first.

Answer (score 1):

### Octave answer:

I believe `immaximas` and `imregionalmax` do exactly what you are looking for (depending on which of the two it is exactly that you are looking for - have a look at their documentation to see the difference).

These are part of the `image` package, but will obviously work on 1D signals too.

For more 'functional' zero-finding functions, there is also `fzero` etc.