# Get a specific data out of the plot in python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to get the frequency value of the second highest peak from the graph. I tried getting the frequencies which are nonzero, then sorting them in a descending order and getting the second value from that list. But it does not work that way. Below is the code for it. The file for replicating can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/84gngc8si4s2fdz/Pipe03_2.csv?dl=0).

```
n = len(time)
fhat_A = np.fft.fft(channelA, n)
PSD_A = fhat_A * np.conj(fhat_A)/n
freq_A = (1/(0.0001*n)) * np.arange(n)
L_A = np.arange(1,np.floor(n/2),dtype='int')

plt.plot(freq_A[L_A], PSD_A[L_A], 'k', label='Noise_A')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD [G^2/Hz]')
plt.title('Noise in Channel A Pipe03_2')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.6, -0.2), ncol=4)
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 300
plt.show()
```

The plot looks like below and I would like to know the PSD value of the red marked line. Is there a better way to do it? Only the real values are enough.
[image: The resultant plot]

**EDIT:**
Following is the code and result on using find_peaks. I do not understand why there are so many peaks shown on the x-axis.

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

peaks, _ = find_peaks(PSD_A[L_A], distance=30)
plt.plot(freq_A[L_A], PSD_A[L_A], 'k', label='Noise_A')
plt.plot(peaks, PSD_A[L_A][peaks], 'xr')
```

[image: Peak_plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Peak-finding algorithm for Python/SciPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713335/peak-finding-algorithm-for-python-scipy)

Comment: I did not think of treating it as peaks for some reason but yes this works partially. I don't understand why there are so many peaks shown in the x-axis as well. I have added the picture in the original post.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612432/6144626) highlights the importance of the parameters `width`, `threshold`, `distance` and `prominence`. You're only using `distance` to identify peaks, but I'd suggest you explore these other parameters a little more - `prominence` is likely to be particularly relevant for weeding out unwanted peaks.

Comment: Yeah I tried all of them but I always get the peak on the x-axis too. I found width and distance to be the most useful for my application though.

Answer (score 0):

If many frequencies are not zero, and therefore your peaks are formed by many points, sorting will not be useful (e.g. you'll get just a point next to the max). Finding peaks in a signal can be complicated. I suggest to use [peakutils](https://peakutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
See the tutorial there: if your signal is `x,y`, it's as simple as

```
indexes = peakutils.indexes(y, thres=0.5, min_dist=30)
print(indexes)
print(x[indexes], y[indexes])
```

Comment: Thanks, I could not install this package. I will try again later. But what is the difference between peakutils and find_peak ?